# Consulta em um banco de questões que não pode retornar acertos

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um banco de questões organizado da seguinte forma:

questoes:

```
    ID | pergunta            | a    | b     | c    | d      | e     | correta
    1  | Qual meu nome?      | joao | pedro | jose | mateus | lucas | pedro
    2  | Qual a minha idade? | 15   | 18    | 20   | 22     | 25    | 18
```

Quando o usuário acessa sua página de perfil, uma pergunta aleatória deste banco de dados deverá aparecer pra ele. No entanto, perguntas que ele já acertou no passado não deverão aparecer novamente.

Para isso, tentei criar uma nova tabela que relacionasse as questões com o usuário, como no exemplo abaixo:

cad_questoes:

```
id_tabela | id_questao | id_usuario | acerto
1         | 1          | 2          | sim
2         | 2          | 2          | nao
3         | 1          | 1          | sim
```

Para pedir a pergunta ao banco de dados que será mostrada ao usuário, utilizo o seguinte comando no PHP/MySQL:

```
$busca_questoes = "SELECT * FROM cad_questoes 
                    INNER JOIN questoes ON cad_questoes.id_questao = questoes.ID 
                    WHERE acerto='nao' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
```

No entanto, para que este comando funcione na prática, eu teria que atualizar o banco de dados cad_questoes manualmente para notificar que existem perguntas que não foram respondidas, mas eu gostaria que isso fosse feito automaticamente.

Minha pergunta é: Como solicitar uma pergunta ao banco de dados que o usuário não tenha respondido ela e como fazer essa verificação?

Espero que tenha conseguido ser claro, fico a disposição para fornecer quaisquer informações que contribuam para a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer seria buscando no banco todas questões foram respondidas por qualquer usuário exceto o em questão, na query a seguir eu utilizei DISTINCT para não retornar perguntas repetidas.

```
$buscaQuestoes = "SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM cad_questoes as cq
        INNER JOIN questoes as q ON cq.id_questao = q.ID 
        WHERE acerto = 'nao' 
        WHERE cq.id_usuario <> '$idUsuario'";
```

Outro método possível é adicionar uma coluna `cad_questoes.respondida` para identificar se a questão já foi respondida, também seria necessário inicializar uma linha pra cada questão ao criar um novo usuário.

Comment: Sobre criar uma coluna cad_questoes.respondida, qual seria a diferença para a coluna já existente cad_questoes.acerto? Sobre a outra sugestão, qual seria o benefício em saber a resposta de outros usuários e como isso evitaria que questões repetidas aparecessem para o usuário em questão? Obrigado pelos comentários!

Comment: @PedroSchimmelpfeng pelo que eu entendi do seu schema,  a coluna `cq.acerto` guarda se o usuário acertou a pergunta ou não, o que eu sugeri é salvar se ele já respondeu ou não. Talvez não ficou claro, mas pensei que todos usuários reponderiam as mesmas perguntas, por isso que disse pra fazer uma query buscando todas perguntas que o usuário logado não respondeu.

Comment: você tem razão, mas eu queria evitar ter que criar uma nova linha para cada usuário criado, como você mencionou... Até por que eu também teria que fazer isso para cada nova questão que eu inserisse no banco de dados, não?